# How do I find gems that depend on a given gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to search for all gems that rely on a certain rubygem?

For example, I'd like to ask for all gems in gemcutter that rely on the test-unit gem.

**Background**: I'm looking to see how other gems handle the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620342/how-do-i-add-conditional-rubygem-requirements-to-a-gem-specification).

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and found that some of the other suggestions for this question are now defunct. I came up with a 2-step solution that worked for me.

The following unix-y script will tell you all the gems your gems depend on:

```
gem list | egrep '^.*[ ]' -o | gem dependency
```

Then I just searched for the culprit in the output.

Comment: This grep fails if there is more than one version of any gem installed.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for gems with test-unit- brings up a few gems with test-unit- dependencies:

> gem search test-unit-

Also, you can search your local gems dependencies with my [gem grep plugin](http://github.com/cldwalker/gem_grep#readme)

> gem grep -f dependencies test-unit

In a future release I plan to support searching remote gem dependencies ...

Comment: This should really be integrated into rubygems itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Google + Gemcutter](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agemcutter.org+dependencies+addressable+-replacement).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
gem dependency GEMNAME --reverse_dependencies
```

Credit where credit is due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15079152/4970976.