# How to find out which gems depdend on gem X

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find gems that depend on a given gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694594/how-do-i-find-gems-that-depend-on-a-given-gem)

I want to find out which gems depend on e.g. one of my gems, so i can see if i would break anything, is this supported/possible ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this question is a duplicate of [How do I find gems that depend on a given gem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694594/how-do-i-find-gems-that-depend-on-a-given-gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gem-dependent](http://github.com/grosser/gem-dependent) tells you...